# React Jest define global component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Is it possible to define the global component at top?

Example

```
it("test 1", () => {
    const component= shallow(<Component {...inputProps}
      onChange={onChange} />);

    ...
  });

  it("test 2", () => {
    const component= shallow(<Component
        {...inputProps}
        onChange={onChange}
        onChange1={onChange1}
      />),
  });
....
```

In the above example we are using same Component for testing but only difference is that Props are different.

Is there any way to define component at top. something like as shown in below

Example

```
const c_component =<Component {...inputProps}
      onChange={onChange} />

it("test 1", () => {
    const component= shallow(c_component );

    ...
  });

  it("test 2", () => {
    const component= shallow(c_component( 
        onChange1={onChange1}
      )),
  });
....
```

Comment: Where does inputProps come from?

Comment: @estus common object define at the top of unit cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be helper function with necessary parameters, e.g.:

```
getComponentWrapper = props =>
  shallow(<Component {...inputProps} {...props} onChange={onChange} />);

...

const component = getComponentWrapper({ onChange1 });
```